# How to show associated product in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have use getProductdetail() fuction data send by json in datatable front page.

Comment: specify the question

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)